# Drawing a square in a website using three.js

Tags: three.js

Why does the following code not draw a complete square?

```
var square = new THREE.Geometry();
      square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
      square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 100, 0));
      square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 0));
      square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0));
      square.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
      square.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2));

      var line = new THREE.Line(square, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 }));
      scene.add(line);
```

i get the following result:
[image]

Comment: You need to also draw the last line back to 0,0,0.

Comment: thanks, but how will this work with the face3

Comment: just ignore the last vector?

Answer (score 6):

```
square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 100, 0));
square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 0));
square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0));

square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

square.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
square.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2));

var line = new THREE.Line(square, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 }));
scene.add(line);
```